# Can lineskip depend on how close the boxes are horizontally?

Tags: line-spacing, plain-tex, baseline

TeX adds lineskip when two lines would get too close together. However, this ought to depend on whether the conflicting boxes in question are near each other horizontally, not just vertically. Is there a way to have this done automatically? See the following for an example where (with the parameters chosen) the extra glue is not necessary. If the two integrals were close to each other, then glue should be added, but not in the present case.

```
\baselineskip=10pt
\lineskiplimit=1pt
\lineskip=1pt

aaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaa
aaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaa
aaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaa
aaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaa
aaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaa
aaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaa
aaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaa $\int_{a_n} u\,dx$ aaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaa        aaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaa $\int_{a_n} u\,dx$ aaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa     aaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaa
aaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaa
aaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaa

\bye
```

[image]

Comment: This is possible but not easy and I don't know of an out-of-the-box solution that exists. You could use LuaTeX and scan through the lines in the `post_line_break` filter to determine if tall elements overlap horizontally and insert a negative space between lines if that is not the case. This problem is similar to the identification of "rivers" but instead of vertically-aligned spaces you are looked for vertically-aligned tall content.

Comment: using `\smash` to "disappear" the extra height or depth is the method i would use.  but it's necessary to actually inspect the results to make sure that no "crashes" have occurred.

Comment: I feel like it may be possible with the output routine but it will be some pretty advanced wizardry; see [Output routines part IV: horizontal techniques](https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb15-1/tb42salomon-output.pdf) for some ideas. A LuaTeX approach would turn out to be substantially less work and much more comprehensible.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid any general and automatic solution is impossible since TeX works with lines as with boxes, i.e. the information where exactly is the problematic point within the finished line gets lost.

Comment: Perhaps it is possible to save information (horizontal location) for each line when adding each `\vbox`, comparing the maximum height and depth in the current line (`\hbox`) so far to those of the current `\vbox`. After all, that information is used to place the `\vbox`es, so TeX has to know it.

Comment: Perhaps it is possible, but you would have to go deep into TeX's internals — way deeper then my knowledge reaches. As far as I understand the matter, TeX first looks for places to break lines within a paragraph (in one to three passes, using \pretolerance, \tolerance and \emergencystretch respectively; and boxes may shift significantly within a specific line during the respective passes) and for that it only needs to know widths of the boxes (plus kerning &c., of course), and only when that's done it puts lines into the vertical list, for which it needs to calculate their heights and depths.